# Four-distance problem

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request

A Problem due to Steinhaus is the following: do there exists a point in the plane at rational distance from the corners of the unit square?

Please give me a reference if this problem is solved.

Comment: The problem is still open. Cf. http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RationalDistanceProblem.html